# why not a lifting of $f$ is map $ \widetilde{f} : X \to E$ such that $p\circ f=\widetilde{f} $

Tags: algebraic-topology

**Definition  of lift**

let $p : E \to B$ be  a map . If $f$ is a  continious mapping of some  space $X$ into $ B $,a lifting of $f$  is  map $ \widetilde{f} : X \to E$  such that $p\circ \widetilde{f} =f$

My confusion is that  why not a lifting of $f$  is  map $ \widetilde{f} : X \to E$  such that $p\circ f=\widetilde{f} $

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because you can't compose $p$ with $f$. $p$ is a map from $E$ to $B$ and $f$ is a map from $X$ to $B$. Because the domain of $p$ is $E$ and the codomain of $f$ is $B$, we can't actually form a composite $p \circ f$.